# can i define k elem in random.sample function as an variable?

Tags: python, tkinter, random

I am begginer in Python. And what I am trying to do is make a random text from the list generator, in which you can choose how many things from the list you want to print out. When im trying to make *k*=var in which var=Entry(...). It gives me this error: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'. If you can give me tips to improve my skills and knowledge Id be really happy.

*k* determines how many items from the list I wanna print out:

```
def nahodny_generator():
    list = ["more", "more1", "more3"]
    sampling = random.sample(list, k=2)
    oklbl = Label(root, text=sampling)
    oklbl.grid(row=6, column=0)
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the text instead of linking to an image of it.

Comment: Please show the actual code that causes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your code into a state where I was able to run it and I didn't see any errors:

```
import random
from tkinter import Label, Widget
from typing import Optional

root: Optional[Widget] = None


def nahodny_generator() -> None:
    words = ["more", "more1", "more3"]
    sampling = random.sample(words, k=2)
    oklbl = Label(root, text=sampling)
    oklbl.grid(row=6, column=0)


nahodny_generator()  # no exceptions raised?
```

One probable bug I noticed is that `sampling` is a `List[str]` (note that `list` is the name of Python's list class, and you probably don't want to name your own variables that) and you're passing it as a parameter called `text`, which I would assume expects a `str` (`tkinter` doesn't have type declarations though so it's not obvious that's the case).

Nothing in the code you shared uses the `<=` operator so the specific error you saw is coming from some other piece of it.  When you get an error, the message will include the exact file and line number that it came from; you can use that to narrow down the source of the bug.

Comment: Thank you for ur response, yes in this way I got it functioning. But the next step is to set k parametr equal to some variable which stores the data from the entry. For example i type in the entry 5 and thats the number of things from the list, that will get printed out.

Comment: `print(random.sample(words, k=int(input(f"How many things? (max {len(words)}): "))))`

Answer (score -1):

The function `nahodny_generator` is referenced in Button command, and I want to push that button with the entry inside and print out the amount of things in a list determined by the entry. Also I am using tkinter GUI and if you could give me some tips where to continue after overcoming the beginner level I would be very happy.

Comment: Please don't post additions or comments to your question as answers.